# Validation not working on Map keys in RestController

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, bean-validation

Using Spring Boot 2.2.6, given this Controller:

```kotlin
@RestController
@Validated
class MyController {
    @GetMapping("foo")
    fun getFirmwareVersionDifference(
        @RequestParam @Valid versions: @Valid Map<
            @Pattern(regexp = "a|b|c")
            String, String>
    ): String {
       // …
    }
}
```

I would expect the request `foo?d=any` to throw a `ConstraintViolationException`, but the controller is called normally.

I have a `MethodValidationPostProcessor` in my context and it works for other validations. If I change the RequestParam to `@RequestParam @Valid @Length(min=3) installedFirmwareVersion: String` it works as expected fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a kotlin compiler bug / missing feature: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13228

As documented in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-35843 this is partially solved in kotlin 1.3.70.

Here's how you can set the compiler flag in `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xemit-jvm-type-annotations")
        jvmTarget = "11" // at least 8 should work, I only tested 11
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, at least in the tests code is still not validating. Kotlin version is 1.4.21. Works only with @field:..

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13228#focus=Comments-27-4647157.0-0

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my answer is not a correction to the one you are looking for but it certainly does checks the validation you are trying to do in your controller.

```
import in.silentsudo.validators.annotations.RequestMap;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapParamValidator implements ConstraintValidator<RequestMap, Map<String, String>> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Map<String, String> stringStringMap, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return stringStringMap.containsKey("a") || stringStringMap.containsKey("c") || stringStringMap.containsKey("b");
    }
}
```

```
import in.silentsudo.validators.MapParamValidator;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Constraint(validatedBy = {MapParamValidator.class})
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RequestMap {
    String message() default "Invalid Request Map";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Controller implementation:

```
@GetMapping("foo")
    public String getFirmwareVersionDifference(
            @RequestParam @Valid
            @RequestMap
                    Map<String, String> versions) {

        return "OK";
    }
```

Please make sure to add `@Validated` on controller like this:

```
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/somepath")
public class StatusController {
...
}
```

If everything works well, you should get something like this

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
getFirmwareVersionDifference.versions: Invalid Request Map
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: getFirmwareVersionDifference.versions: Invalid Request Map
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! After half a day I just found the problem: it's a kotlin compiler bug/missing feature https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13228

Comment: Plain vanilla java is awesome!

Comment: Would have been my choice too ;)